# Protege Ontology Help linking sub classes

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have got an ontology for hybrid control system. i have two classes an actuator class and a controller class. Their sub classes are
actuator class: window, curtain and air conditioner.
Controller class: PI controller and Supervisory Controller.

I want to create a link such that pi controller controls AC whereas Supervisory controller controls both curtain and window.

Now i have made this relation in the object properties but i don't how to specify the link.
I have defined the relation in the object properties

Comment: You'll need to be more specific when you say that "PI controller controls AC".  Do you mean that "each PI controller controls exactly one AC" "each PI controller controls only AC", etc.?  Similarly for supervisory controller.  Once you've pinned down exactly what that means, it will be a straightforward subclass axiom. E.g., **PI_Controller subClassOf (controls only AC)**.

Comment: yes i meant to say PI controller controls only AC..Supervisory controller only controls window and curtain. thank you for the help